# Multi parameters in url django

Tags: django, django-urls

maybe this question is repeated but I can't find any solution exactly what I need. I need to pass two differents parameters to one url in a `DetailView` (Im not working with function views, mostly of possible solutions that I have found are with function views). I have some views done but it does not make sense put it here because are not working. How can I achieve this? For example:

```
url(r'^crear-puntointeraccion/(?P<pk>[-_\w]+)/(?P<point_id>[-_\w]+)/$'
```

And if it does not find a pk or a point_id show 404, I have something done but only takes one parameter, the other parameter it does not taking it because if I write some non-existent ID anyway show the result.

Comment: the url you are creating will respond only to those urls which have both the parameters. You can create more urls for different cases when you will only have pk.

Comment: _if I write some non-existent ID_ You mean point_id?

Comment: It's much more maintenable to break down the logic to two different views rather than create a single "fat" view.

Comment: No, I mean the pk. 

@petkostas I dont understand how can I make two differents views if I need to display a query that get some id's from URL. How can I do that?

Comment: To access the extra parameter, override either the get_queryset method, or the method that needs to check for the presence of the point_id (it could be the get_context_data.
You can find info regarding this here:
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: URL does not test if and ID exists or does not, it just test the match with a pattern. if you have not defined what to do if some parameter is not valid, a DetailView will just render the object passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can perform this check by overriding the `get_object()` function of `DetailView`.**

`get_object()` returns the object that the view is displaying. In your view, `DetailView` will perform object lookup by using the `pk` argument. Before this object retrieval process via `pk`, we will add a check to validate the value of `point_id` parameter in the url.

If `point_id` is valid, we call the `super()` method where normal object retrieval and validation by `pk` will occur. If `point_id` is invalid, we raise a `Http404` exception.

```
from django.http import Http404

class MyView(DetailView):
    
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        point_id = self.kwargs.get('point_id')
        # write your logic to validate point_id here
        if not check_valid_point_id(point_id): # assumed 'check_valid_point_id' function validates point_id 
            raise Http404("Invalid point id") # raise 404 exception on invalid point_id
        return super(MyView, self).get_object(queryset) # call super() on valid point_id
```

**Note:** In the above code, i have assumed a `check_valid_point_id()` function which will take `point_id` as a argument will validate the `point_id`. You can add the logic for `point_id` validation in that function or write your own logic in the `get_object()` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Django detail view expects to find only one url parameter. This is defined by the `pk_url_kwarg` of the DetailView (defaults to pk) or the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg` (which defaults to slug).
In order to access any extra url parameters, you need to override the default DetailView methods. Which one, depends on what is affected by the extra url parameter. If the extra param affects the object that needs to be retrieved, then override the `get_queryset` method of the DetailView class. In there you can access parameters through the `self.kwargs` object.
If your url parameter is only needed as additional data to load (among maybe the primary object that is requested), then override the `get_context_data` method, the later can be overriden by the following way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourClassView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # context now holds the context of your view, you can add extra data to
    # it with the following way:
    context['mydata'] = "Some data"
    # return the context
    return context
```

In the above example your pk will be available in the `self.kwargs` object.